# Notification onClick Intent sends wrong data to Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I am using the newIntent to pass the correct taskId when a notification in my app is clicked. This is the code inside onReceive() of my broadcast receiver:

```
 Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, TaskActivity.class);
    int taskId = intent.getIntExtra("taskId", 0);
    newIntent.putExtra("taskId", intent.getIntExtra("taskId", 0));

      Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra("NotificationTitle"))
                    .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("NotificationText"))
                    .setSmallIcon(intent.getIntExtra("NotificationIcon", 0))
                    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, newIntent, 0))
                    .build();
```

This is the code of the activity that receives the Intent

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("taskId")) {
        currentTask = dataSource.fetchTask(getIntent().getIntExtra("taskId", 0));
    }
```

When I debug, the method getIntExtra() returns a different value than the one in onReceive() of the broadcast receiver.

Any ideas why this happens?

Thank you!

Comment: i suggest you cross check this line of code  `int taskId = intent.getIntExtra("taskId", 0);` by printing the value of taskId. from where you are getting this value?

Comment: The value comes from the intent that is passed in the argument of onreceive(). Before that happens, i set an alarmmanger with the intent with key "taskId". I already printed the value and that is exactly the problem:
When I pass it on to the Alarm Manager it is the same that is received by the broadcast receiver. The activity however, that is started by the click intent of the notification receives a wrong value.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you create the `Notification`, instead of this:

```
.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, newIntent, 0))
```

Do this:

```
.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, newIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
```

Your problem is that you are reusing the same `PendingIntent` multiple times. You need to make sure that the "extras" in the `PendingIntent` are updated every time you use one.

NOTE: If you have several `Notification`s available at the same time, then you need to make sure that you create unique `PendingIntent`s for each one. To do this, make sure that the `requestCode` parameter (second argument in `PendingIntent.getActivity()`) are different for each `Notification` (you could, for example, use your `taskId` as a unique `requestCode`).

Comment: Thank you. `requestCode` got me. Why this isn't properly documented is beyond my understanding.